# Import DAZ3D facial expressions

Tags: animation

I’m able to import a pose to Blender but the facial expression doesn’t come with it. I've tried some things I read online but none resolved this problem.

I’m using Diffeomorphic to import the poses but when I import it doesn’t apply the facial expression! Did I miss a step?

Comment: Sorry, but on this site we are answering questions about problems using Blender and its officially shipped addons, for third-party addons please ask respective developers. Also on the Daz3D site there are discussion forums regarding Blender and Diffeomorphic.